# Glocal scope for my polymer webcomponent css

Tags: polymer

I want the css rules in my webcomponent to be global in my page, not only in this local dom.

```
<dom-module id="x-custom">

  <template>

    <style>
      h1{
        color: red;
      }
      <!-- I want not only this local h1 to be red but also all h1 in my page -->
    </style>

     <h1>Hello stackoverflow<h1>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-custom'
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://plnkr.co/edit/snzeXNnnXGz5fjCFqzy3?p=preview) an example on how you can do it. But this will work only in case of `shady-dom` it will fail for `shadow-dom`. For shadow dom one option is to bind color of `h1` wherever to use it to same default CSS variable something like

```
 h1{
  color:var(--my-color,--default-color);
        //or 
  color:var(--my-color,var(--default-color)); //if you are using polymer 1.7.
}
```

And then you can assign the value to `--default-color` in your `app-theme` or in index.html like

```
<style is="custom-style">
  :root{      //you can use html instead of :root if you are using polymer 1.7
    --default-color:red;
  }
</style>
```

Second, option will be to create a `shared-style` and include it everywhere you use `h1` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly what you are looking for, shared styles may be an option even though they will need to be explicitly included for all your components.

> To share style declarations between elements, you can package a set of style declarations inside a  element. In this section, a  holding styles is called a style module for convenience.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules